# How can you pdfjoin smartly different sized pictures?

Tags: pdf

I'm running the default `pdfjoin` and getting results like this:

[image]

**How can you `pdfjoin` different sized pictures?**
My first idea is to add an empty page in front of all things.

Comment: Is it possible to make the example reproducible? Which options of pdfjoin have you tried? How does http://superuser.com/questions/352795/joining-two-pdfs-with-slightly-different-page-size-with-pdfjoin-under-linux-or-m work for you?

Comment: Default and then "--paper a4paper".

Comment: pdfsam does that nicely.

Comment: @ToDo Which package has this pdfsam? I am in OSX 10.10.3 Yosemite now and it is not in Brew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think LaTeX is good tool here. 
A good approach in the thread [How to rotate image 90 if height overful?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341553/13173) which does not manage to solve the case where both dimensions are bigger than the page size. 
I did not find anything relevant in `pdfjoin` and/or `exiftool` for the task.

The case has to manage page orientation of many pictures, not only single pictures. 
`exiftool` is about one picture, while LaTeX can nicle handle the page orientation of many pictures.